# C heap address changes between runs while other addresses persist

Tags: c, assembly, linker, heap-memory, memory-address

The heap troubles me because I don't understand who creates it, who maintains it and who decides where it should be... This test shows part of my conundrum:

Source code:

```
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int a;
int b = 5;

int * getMeAPointer() {
    int * e = malloc(4);
    *e = 5;
    return e;
}


void main() {
    a = 5;
    int c = 5;
    int * d = (int *) 0x405554;
    *d = 5;
    int * e = getMeAPointer();
    printf("Address of a located in .bss is %x\n", &a);
    printf("Address of b located in .data is %x\n", &b);
    printf("Address of c located in stack is %x\n", &c);
    printf("Address of d located in stack is %x\n", &d);
    printf("Address of *d located absolutely is %x\n", d);
    printf("Address of e located in stack is %x\n", &e);
    printf("Address of *e located on heap is %x\n", e);
    printf("Address of getMeAPointer() located in .text is %x\n", getMeAPointer);
    free(e);
}
```

Example printouts:

```
Address of a located in .bss is 0x405068
Address of b located in .data is 0x402000
Address of c located in stack is 0x22ff1c
Address of d located in stack is 0x22ff18
Address of *d located absolutely is 0x405554
Address of e located in stack is 0x22ff14
Address of *e located on heap is 0x541738
Address of getMeAPointer() located in .text is 0x4013b0

Address of a located in .bss is 0x405068
Address of b located in .data is 0x402000
Address of c located in stack is 0x22ff1c
Address of d located in stack is 0x22ff18
Address of *d located absolutely is 0x405554
Address of e located in stack is 0x22ff14
Address of *e located on heap is 0x3a1738
Address of getMeAPointer() located in .text is 0x4013b0

Address of a located in .bss is 0x405068
Address of b located in .data is 0x402000
Address of c located in stack is 0x22ff1c
Address of d located in stack is 0x22ff18
Address of *d located absolutely is 0x405554
Address of e located in stack is 0x22ff14
Address of *e located on heap is 0x351738
Address of getMeAPointer() located in .text is 0x4013b0

....etc....
```

Now these are my concerns:

1. Why is the heap moving around and none of the other segments? This is on a Windows 7 OS with MinGW and this file was compiled with GCC without further flags (I don't believe this is an example of Address Space Layout Randomization).
2. Who decides where the heap should be? I belive the linker reserves a place for the heap (I've seen heap symbols in symbol tables) but when is the exact address decided on, is it a runtime thing done by the RUNNABLE itself (C code) AFTER loading, or is it done by the linker / loader / dynamic linker while LOADING the program right BEFORE execution?
3. Is there any way to set the heap address in ld? I have understood that I can set all segments except stack (since that's built into the kernel of the OS) but can I set the heap address?
4. The way I understands it, the heap is not really an assembly language construct and we don't have access to a heap if we choose to just do assembly programming. Therefore it is a C construct but I'm interested in how that affects the life of the heap (i mean we speak of the heap like it's on the same level as the segments and the stack but if it isn't, then that should give it a whole lot of other conditions)... is this correct and can anyone tell me something more about it?

I've Google'd all day long to be honest and I'm hungry for some answers!

Comment: Your example printouts are all almost equal...

Comment: no.. look at what e points to which is in the heap... that's the point of my whole question...

Comment: Oh, yes, right. That's the only interesting here, actually.

Answer (score 5):

> Why is the heap moving around and none of the other segments?

Because dynamic memory allocation is, well, *dynamic.* The address you get back from `malloc()` depends on where a sufficiently big chunk of free memory can be found **at the very moment your program is being executed.** Obviously, since there are other programs too, this changes over time.

> Who decides where the heap should be?

The developers of your operating system.

> I belive [sic!] the linker reserves a place for the heap

Rarely. On most implementations I've seen, it's entirely a runtime thing. (It's not that it's impossible that the linker have something to do with it, but still.)

> Is there any way to set the heap address in ld?

If there is, it's surely [documented](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ld). (Assuming that the `ld` you are referring to is the linker in your toolchain.)

> [...] I can set all segments except stack (since that's built into the kernel of the OS)

I don't think I fully understand what you are saying, but "the stack" is not "built in to the kernel". Generally, the stack address is either statically hard-coded into the executable or it is referred to using relative instructions.

> the heap is not really an assembly language construct and we don't have access to a heap if we choose to just do assembly programming.

But yes you do. I'm not familiar with Windows, but on most Unixes, you can use the `brk()` and/or `sbrk()` syscalls.

> Therefore it is a C construct

Your logic is flawed. Just because something is not an assembly thing, it does **not** automatically mean that it's a C thing. In fact, there's no such thing as "the heap" or "the stack" in C. In C, there is only automatic, static and dynamic storage duration, which are not tied to specific manners of implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Ok so then I take it that the C code in the runnable is getting the space through malloc() which is a C construct. However, you say that there are other programs as well but that shouldn't matter since every process has its own virtual environment (in my system). Are you saying the OS prefers to use physical addresses for the heap rather than virtual and therefore they change between runs?

Comment: @fast-reflexes No. I'm just saying that unspecified behavior is unspecified behavior.

Comment: Ok.. but then I'd like to know about the process... is the heap an OS thing then? Since the OS is returning the space? If I make a small program in an embedded system in just assembly, there won't be a heap but there will be a stack and the other segments.. that's what I mean by the heap notbeing an assembly construct...

Comment: For the Windows case, you have `GetProcessHeap()` (or even `HeapCreate()`), `HeapAlloc()`, `HeapFree()`, etc. In MSVC at least, the C runtime library heap is just a very thin wrapper around an OS heap.

Comment: @fast-reflexes Yes, it's an OS thing. No, embedded-ness has nothing to do with it being available or not.

Comment: And also, what I meant regarding the stack is that the start address of the stack can't be set and that it's hard coded into the kernel (where the start address should be, THEN it's hardcoded into the runnable.. at least I can't set it in ld)

Comment: @fast-reflexes: Phyiscal addresses are yet something very different. In a modern OS you'll never get real physical addresses, unless you're coding a device driver (and even in that case the virtual address you use to access it from an application will be different from the physical address the hardware sees).

Comment: What do you mean embeded-ness has nothing to do with it being available or not? If I have just assmebly language, then there won't be any definitions of a heap in the memory right (except if I make one myself) whereas there will still be data, text and bss segments, no? I thought dynamic allocation wasn't possible in assembly?

Comment: Also, isn't malloc() just reserving a space WITHIN the heap space, the general heap space already being defined before the first call to malloc() but the specific spot for a certain chunk of data not being decided upon?

Comment: Does the embedded system have an OS? If so, it probably has dynamic memory of some kind. If not, then yes, you'd have to roll your own heap. On the second one: it's an implementation detail. RTL's malloc() may preallocare, or it may ask the OS for memory on the first call. In the latter case, the address will be up to the OS. The address you'll get will be probably driven by the current layout of the process' virtual address space - the set of DLLs loaded and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

A variety of factors will influence where the heap will reside, i.e.

- Base address of the application
- Libraries required by the application
- What the operating system allocates to the application

The C heap is (simplified) just a huge block of memory which is maintained by the runtime of the application, so the effective address you get when calling malloc() is defined by that runtime. The runtime is different between compiler versions and different vendors. The *entire* memory block that the runtime uses as a heap is obtained from the operating system at application startup. Here, the operating system may return a different address each time the application is run. Therefore, heap addresses are not predictable. If your application starts allocating and deallocating memory during its run, it will even get "more" random, because now the runtime needs to find free blocks between currently allocated blocks and so on. So unless the sequence of allocations/deallocations is exactly the same between runs, you will get entirely different addresses, even if the base heap address is the same.